# Ansible module postgresql_query gives error

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I have a code like this:

```
- name: Check if postgres is running
  community.postgresql.postgresql_ping:
    db: "{{ stl_database }}"
    port: "{{ stl_postgres_port }}"
    login_host: "{{ db_host }}"
    login_password: "{{ postgres_password }}"
  register: postgres_availabe

- name: Check the database versions
  postgresql_query:
    db: "{{ stl_database }}"
    port: "{{ stl_postgres_port }}"
    login_host: "{{ db_host }}"
    login_user: postgres
    login_password: "{{ postgres_password }}"
    query: "{{ get_db_version }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  register: db_version_return
  when: postgres_availabe.is_available == true
```

It uses two community modules which I have installed with `ansible-galaxy collection install community.postgresql`.

The first module checks if postgresql is running on the remote server {{ db_host }}, the second module run a query(defined by {{ get_db_version }}) to get the code version from the postgresql DB on the remote server {{ db_host }}. When I run the code, I am getting the below output:

```
TASK [Check if postgres is running] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Wednesday 08 June 2022  16:13:25 +0000 (0:00:00.030)       0:00:01.676 ******** 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Check the database versions] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Wednesday 08 June 2022  16:13:25 +0000 (0:00:00.419)       0:00:02.095 ******** 
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user (rc: 1, err: chmod: invalid mode: ‘A+user:postgres:rx:allow’\nTry 'chmod --help' for more information.\n}). For information on working around this, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-core/2.12/user_guide/become.html#risks-of-becoming-an-unprivileged-user"}
```

The first module works. But the 2nd one errors. When I use "-vvv" in the CLI and I got the details like this:

```
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: philip.shangguan
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~philip.shangguan && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /var/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1654700298.6125453-341391-58979494615213 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1654700298.6125453-341391-58979494615213="` echo /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1654700298.6125453-341391-58979494615213 `" ) && sleep 0'
redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.postgresql_query to community.postgresql.postgresql_query
Using module file /home/philip.shangguan/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/modules/postgresql_query.py
<127.0.0.1> PUT /home/philip.shangguan/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-341261szx105mk/tmppy72gy9u TO /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1654700298.6125453-341391-58979494615213/AnsiballZ_postgresql_query.py
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'setfacl -m u:postgres:r-x /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1654700298.6125453-341391-58979494615213/ /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1654700298.6125453-341391-58979494615213/AnsiballZ_postgresql_query.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1654700298.6125453-341391-58979494615213/ /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1654700298.6125453-341391-58979494615213/AnsiballZ_postgresql_query.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chown postgres /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1654700298.6125453-341391-58979494615213/ /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1654700298.6125453-341391-58979494615213/AnsiballZ_postgresql_query.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod +a '"'"'postgres allow read,execute'"'"' /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1654700298.6125453-341391-58979494615213/ /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1654700298.6125453-341391-58979494615213/AnsiballZ_postgresql_query.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod A+user:postgres:rx:allow /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1654700298.6125453-341391-58979494615213/ /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1654700298.6125453-341391-58979494615213/AnsiballZ_postgresql_query.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1654700298.6125453-341391-58979494615213/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
```

It looks like the module is trying to do `chmod +a` and `chmod A+user:postgres:rx:allow`. If I manually try the commands, I got:

```
chmod A+user:postgres:rx:allow rename_appdb.sql
chmod: invalid mode: ‘A+user:postgres:rx:allow’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
```

Any idea why the module is doing that? I have the same code running on another ansible server that I used before and it has been working(still today). But when I try to run this on a new ansible server that I installed the community modules yesterday, I got the errors above.

Thanks!

Comment: You do not need to become the postgres user to execute a `postgresql_query`. Remove your `become` and `become_user` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try and let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As β.εηοιτ.βε suggested, I removed the `become` and `become_user` from the code and it works.

The new code:

```
- name: Check the database versions
  postgresql_query:
    db: "{{ stl_database }}"
    port: "{{ stl_postgres_port }}"
    login_host: "{{ db_host }}"
    login_user: postgres
    login_password: "{{ postgres_password }}"
    query: "{{ get_db_version }}"
  register: db_version_return
  when: postgres_availabe.is_available == true
```

and the result:

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************Wednesday 08 June 2022  20:16:19 +0000 (0:00:00.039)       0:00:02.880 ******** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "8-8-3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the package `acl` to get it running

```
sudo apt-get install acl
```